# Why doesn't this BibLaTeX work?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

**Preamble**

```
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{\section{#1}}
\addbibresource{sources.bib} % replace this with your actual bibfile name
\usepackage{csquotes}
```

**Document**

```
\parencite{wikiparsing}
\printbibliography
```

**sources.bib**

```
@misc{wikiparsing,
author = {Wikipedia},
title = {Parsing},
howpublished = {\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing}},
month = {},
year = {2020},
note = {Zuletzt aufgerufen am 13.06.2020}
}
```

**Log**

[image: BibLaTeX error message]

**Data structure**

[image: Data structure]

**Comment**

I am using TexStudio as editor.

**Leistungsüberwachung**

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)
Capacity: max_strings=200000, hash_size=200000, hash_prime=170003
The top-level auxiliary file: cs_workshop.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file cs_workshop.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file cs_workshop.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file cs_workshop.aux
You've used 0 entries,
            0 wiz_defined-function locations,
            83 strings with 496 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 0 in all, are:
= -- 0
> -- 0
< -- 0
+ -- 0
- -- 0
* -- 0
:= -- 0
add.period$ -- 0
call.type$ -- 0
change.case$ -- 0
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 0
duplicate$ -- 0
empty$ -- 0
format.name$ -- 0
if$ -- 0
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 0
missing$ -- 0
newline$ -- 0
num.names$ -- 0
pop$ -- 0
preamble$ -- 0
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 0
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 0
swap$ -- 0
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 0
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 0
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 0
(There were 3 error messages)
```

Comment: Open the file with Typ "Leistungsüberwachung" in texstudio (use the texstudio menu, don't double click) and show what it says.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you, I updated my post

Comment: That shows that you did run bibtex and not biber. Configure your editor to use biber https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: Since `biblatex` fully supports online entries, you can change the type of `wikiparsing` from `@misc` to `@online`. Furthermore, `howpublished = {\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing}},` can be replaced with the more semantic `url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing},` and `note = {Zuletzt aufgerufen am 13.06.2020}` with `urldate= {2020-06-13},`. I'd also drop the empty `month` field.